# What definition is adjusted to the word 'commit' in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> This tawdry tableau, which I’m not proud to **commit** to the page, goes a
>   long way toward explaining the unlikely spot I find myself in at the
>   moment. (from [here](https://www.recommendmeabook.com/joshuafoer/moonwalkingwitheinstein))

Which definition is adjusted to the word **commit** in this context?

I tried to find a reasonable definition for this context - in two dictionaries but I am not sure. (See [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/commit?q=COMMIT) and [Oxford](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/commit) for this word)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "commit to page" means *write down* (or *record*).

The expression "commit to paper" is a more common way of saying this and it's specifically defined in [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/commit-to-paper).

Comment: The asker's links have this too, if you dig far enough! Cambridge has "commit sth to paper" and Oxford has the more general "commit something to: Transfer something to (a state or place)".